# Adventure Game Studio Editor in Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04

How do I install Adventure Game Studio [AGS](http://www.adventuregamestudio.co.uk/) Editor in Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus) ? I am pretty sure it can be built for Linux too, I just am not very experienced in building things from source.

Comment: According to https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=14470 AGS has a bronze compatibility level with Wine on Ubuntu. That means, you can try to install Wine and run AGS inside that. You will probably not get 100% satisfying results though. For Wine on Arch Linux, the rating is gold, so it works better there for some reason...

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need Wine in order to install and run Windows software/games.

I will link you to the official [WineHQ Wiki](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu). It has all the information you need to install Wine.

Then is as simple as to install the software just like you would do in windows.

**N.B :** As pointed out by [Byte Commander](https://askubuntu.com/users/367990/byte-commander) A[GS has a bronze compatibility level](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=14470), so you should expect issue installing/running this specific software.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/adventuregamestudio/ags/blob/master/debian/README.md) is a link to a description of how to install it on a variety of Linux platforms, including Ubuntu. It also has debugging information that I won't be showing here.

The following code should be typed into the terminal:
Install dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install git debhelper build-essential pkg-config libaldmb1-dev libfreetype6-dev libtheora-dev libvorbis-dev libogg-dev
```

Download the source with git

```
git clone git://github.com/adventuregamestudio/ags.git
cd ags  # change to the ags directory
```

Build the package `fakeroot debian/rules binary` 

Install it with gdebi `sudo gdebi ../ags_3~git-1_*.deb`

EDIT: Sorry, just realized you were asking for the editor. Yes, you'll need Wine for that unfortunately ([Source](http://www.adventuregamestudio.co.uk/wiki/GNU/Linux))

Comment: Unfortunately, this is just for the engine :/

Comment: Wine gave me error http://imgur.com/a/P53vr